# Saving Blender File to a Shared Folder Results in "Cannot change old file" Error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, network

I'm trying to save a .blend file to a shared folder that has five computers connected to it, but when I save the file, I get a "Cannot change old file (file saved with @)" error. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are the read and write permissions for the directory/file correct?

Comment: They should be. The folder allows others to create and delete files.

Comment: Are there others accessing the file at the same time?

Comment: Yes. There are five computers accessing at the same time. Is that the problem?

Comment: I guess that was the problem. I saved my file directly to my computer to get it from .blend@ back to .blend and then I resaved it in the shared folder. Now it saves again successfully. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know what OS you are dealing with. To have the file work with many  different users they would all need to be part of the same group with read/write/ownership privilleges. Though as workflow I don't see how having many people work simultaneously on the same file would work. The changes made on the file by one file would overwrite whatever the others where doing.

Comment: Okay. I thought it was a Blender problem. I didn't realize it was a permissions/networking issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with saving files while using a computer with a local hard drive (Windows10).
"Cannot change old file (file saved with @)" error occured when I packed external data into my blend files and then tried to save it.
Unpacking external data solved my problem.

Comment: I didn't think about that. I'll try that if that issue occurs again.