# Message "cannot-change-old-file-(file-saved-with-@)" trying to copy objects

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

If I try to copy an object, I get this message: "cannot change old file (file saved with @)". Googling, I see several people getting this message in a variety of circumstances, but none on copying an object.

There are plenty of files with "@" in their name on my system, but no .blend@ files.

The blender animation is created from scratch, no import or such things.

I'm on OpenSuse Tumbleweed; Blender version 2.80.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: That could be a problem with writing permissions. When copying an object to buffer (I assume what *"I try to copy an object"* means) Blender creates .blend file called "copybuffer" or alike, writes it on the disk and saves. If it can't do that for some reason operation will fail with probably similar error. See also  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46736/saving-blender-file-to-a-shared-folder-results-in-cannot-change-old-file-error and https://blenderartists.org/t/cant-save-old-file-with/698669

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the issues in the links you gave already in m google search. In one, the .blend@ is mentioned, which I don't have on my system. In the other, there are external data used, which had to be unpacked - also not an issue here. I searched for "copybuffer "copy" and "buffer", grepping "blend", but no relevant files are shown.